# How can I compare two standard mortality ratios (SMRs)?

Tags: statistical-significance, mortality

I have a population who I separated into three groups: low, medium, high exposure. I calculated the standard mortality ratios [(SMRs)](https://ibis.health.state.nm.us/resource/SMR_ISR.html) for each of this group using a standard population. One of my mentors asked me to do some type of statistical test comparing SMRs in the low versus medium, and low versus high exposure categories. Does anyone know what type of test I can do? Is this even possible? Is there a test for rate ratios?

Comment: See for one approach:   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/466404/poisson-regression-for-modeling-standardized-mortality-ratio-smr